# How to make Entity Framework Core query some of the fields when performing JOIN

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm using LINQ to query data from multiple tables.

```
var test= await _context.Article
.Select(a => new
{
    a.ID,
    a.Title,
    a.CreatedTime,
    a.EditedTime,
    a.Author.UserName,
    a.AuthorID
}).ToListAsync();
```

`Author` is a Navigation property in `Article` class.

But I got this from log:

```
Executed DbCommand (6ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [a].[ID], [a].[AuthorID], [a].[Content], [a].[CreatedTime], [a].[EditedTime], [a].[Title], [a.Author].[Id], [a.Author].[AccessFailedCount], [a.Author].[ConcurrencyStamp], [a.Author].[Email], [a.Author].[EmailConfirmed], [a.Author].[LockoutEnabled], [a.Author].[LockoutEnd], [a.Author].[NormalizedEmail], [a.Author].[NormalizedUserName], [a.Author].[PasswordHash], [a.Author].[PhoneNumber], [a.Author].[PhoneNumberConfirmed], [a.Author].[SecurityStamp], [a.Author].[TwoFactorEnabled], [a.Author].[UserName]
      FROM [Article] AS [a]
      LEFT JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a.Author] ON [a].[AuthorID] = [a.Author].[Id]
      ORDER BY [a].[AuthorID]
```

I just want some of the field, but it queries for all of them. If I delete the `a.Author.UserName` line from my code, it just works as expected.

Am I missed something?

I'm using Entity Framework Core 1.1.0 with Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is already [documented as bug](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6647), fix scheduled for milestone 2.0.0

Comment: Cool. Now the "only" question is when the 2.0.0 is coming and what the people should do with all these bugs until then :)